# Issue with @login_required function in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I'm receiving an error when trying to use the login_required function.

I'm receiving a
TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/login/
registration/login.html
Error.

While I have no directory **Registration**, I have my templates in a folder, templates. I have a login.html template which works fine for the login page.

This is the view`I'm using the login_required function on

```
@login_required(login_url='signin')
def buy_crypto(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        currency = request.POST.get('currency')
        amount = Decimal(request.POST.get('amount'))
        price_per_unit = Decimal(request.POST.get('price_per_unit'))
        purchase = CryptoPurchase(user=request.user, currency=currency, amount=amount, price_per_unit=price_per_unit)
        purchase.save()
        return redirect('index')
    else:
        return render(request, 'buy_crypto.html')
```

My url patterns for User Authentication are in a seperate app in the same project. This app is called accounts.

Here's the accounts/urls.py file

```
from django.urls import path
from cryptoapp import views
from .views import signupView, signinView, signoutView

urlpatterns = [
    path('create/', signupView, name='signup'),
    path('login/', signinView, name='signin'),
    path('signout/', signoutView, name='signout'),
]
```

Here is settings.py file:

```
"""
Django settings for backend project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.1.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ''

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'cryptoapp',
    'djoser',
    'accounts',
    'crispy_forms',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'backend.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'backend.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CustomUser'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
     'http://localhost:3000'
]

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/"
```

If you need any further code please let me know !

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: can you share settings.py? (remove secrets before posting)

Comment: Shared. @HemalPatel

Comment: In your settings.py LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL takes the name of the url . so if you are tyring to redirect to login page use : LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "signin"